Extract file path from Git diff output
I have the following command:
git diff branch1..branch2 | grep '^diff'

...that will output files that contains differences between two branches. Sample output is like this:
diff --git a/path-to-file1/file1.php b/path-to-file1/file1.php
diff --git a/path-to-file2/file2.php b/path-to-file2/file2.php
diff --git a/path-to-file3/file3.php b/path-to-file3/file3.php

How do I amend this command to get only the file path? I want to filter out the "diff --git a/" and "b/path-to-file1/file1.php". So, I want the final output to look like this:
path-to-file1/file1.php
path-to-file2/file2.php
path-to-file3/file3.php

Assume both branches have the same directory structure. So take either the "a/" or "b/" paths.

That's a very backwards way to get files with differences. There's the --name-only option to git diff, which already does that, robustly.
How I found out? I had a similar problem as you when I was new to git, so I read git help diff.

YOU ROCK!!! Thank you!

hahaha, thanks :) Hope this helped :)

when everything else fail, read the (fine) manual ?

Me too! And after finding the option, it took me probably 3 years to stop typing --names-only rather than --name-only.  Cause you know, most of the time, we expect multiple files and multiple names.
